# scanf() function in c

Tags: c

In scanf space and \n is delimiter for the character i/p.
 The below program accepts only two input.
 I could not understand why does it accept two input.Please explain about this behaviour.

```
     char a,b,c;
    scanf("%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c);
    printf("%c%c%c",a,b,c);
    return 0;
```

Comment: It doesn't "accept two inputs", it accepts three consecutive `char`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the characters '123' without seperating them by a space or a carriage return
then a is set to '1', b to '2' and c to '3'. If you seperate the characters by a space ('1 2 3')
then a is set 1, b to ' ' and c to '3'. 
Note, a space is also handled as a input character!!

Answer (score 5):

It *does* accept 3 inputs if you don't put spaces between the input characters.

If you want to allow space(s) between inputs use `scanf("%c %c %c",&a,&b,&c);`.

Comment: Oooooohhhhhh, _that's_ what the OP wanted!  :-)

Comment: it accepts 2 inputs when given scanf("%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c) without space and it accepts three input when given scanf("%c %c %c",&a,&b,&c) with space.

Comment: @Beata: first one reads three consecutive characters (reads space too). Second one reads three non-whitespace characters (so both "123", "1 2 3" and any number of spaces between them works)

Comment: @yi_H:yeah it reads as you have said.I'm little late to understand it.Thanks.